# Capturing extra variables on a match statement assigning a function

Tags: rust, higher-order-functions

I am trying to assign first to a function that returns an attribute of player depending on which condition is being used. In the Int case, I want to just ignore the player and just return the value that is associated with the Int case of ConditionValue. I looked for other solutions to this problem, but was unable to find something that was similiar enough to apply in this case.

```rust
//let first: Fn(&Player) -> u16 = match condition.first {
//let first: dyn Fn(&Player) -> u16 = match condition.first {
let first: fn(&Player) -> u16 = match condition.first {
    // ConditionValue::Int(val) => |_|  val,
    ConditionValue::Int(val) => |_| -> u16 {val},
    ConditionValue::CountInDeck(_) => todo!(),
    ConditionValue::CountTypeInDeck(_) => todo!(),
    ConditionValue::CountInSupply(_) => todo!(),
    ConditionValue::CountAllCardsInDeck => todo!(),
    ConditionValue::CountVp => todo!(),
    ConditionValue::CountOpponentVp => todo!(),
};
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src\strategy.rs:149:37
    |
149 |         ConditionValue::Int(val) => |_| -> u16 {val},
    |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found closure
    |
    = note: expected fn pointer `for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a Player<'b>) -> u16`
                  found closure `[closure@src\strategy.rs:149:37: 149:47]`
note: closures can only be coerced to `fn` types if they do not capture any variables
   --> src\strategy.rs:149:49
    |
149 |         ConditionValue::Int(val) => |_| -> u16 {val},
    |                                                 ^^^ `val` captured here
```

I experimented with the commented out portions of code, couldn't get anything that was promising.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why do you need a closure? And what do you want to return in the other cases?

Comment: Also, please post the full error of `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Comment: Do you really want to capture the outer variable `condition`?  Since you have an unnamed parameter, maybe name and use that instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicates, `fn` (with a lowercase `f`) types are only usable for *actual* function pointers. That means pointers to top-level functions or to closures that don't close around any variables.

You want one of the three function traits. Those are, in order

- `FnOnce` is the trait for functions that can be called once and which takes ownership of their closure.
- `FnMut` is the trait for functions that can be called once *at a time*. These take `&mut` exclusive references to their closure.
- `Fn` is the trait for functions that can be called any number of times. These take `&` immutable references to their closure.

Obviously, `Fn` is the strictest of these, with `FnOnce` being the most general (in the sense that more functions implement `FnOnce` than implement `Fn`), so use items later in the above list if you can, since they provide stronger guarantees to the caller.

But we actually have another problem. I'm going to assume you're using `Fn` from here on in, but everything I say here applies to the other two as well. `Fn` is a trait, so if we want to use it as a trait object, we need to write `dyn Fn(&Player) -> u16`. But `dyn` trait object types are *unsized*, so they can't be stored in local variables or directly returned from functions. We need to wrap it in something that can handle an unsized type, and the usual way to do that is with a `Box`, which stores a pointer to arbitrary (potentially unsized) data.

So the type you're looking for is `Box<dyn Fn(&Player) -> u16>` (again, replace `Fn` with `FnMut` or `FnOnce` as needed). And you'll need to wrap the value in a box explicitly.

```
let first: Box<dyn Fn(&Player) -> u16> = match condition.first {
    ConditionValue::Int(val) => Box::new(|_| -> u16 {val}),
    ...
};
```